# How can I export to CAD in a way that will align with Google Earth imagery?

Tags: google-earth, cad, design

I am trying to align GIS layers exported to CAD with GE imagery but am not achieving good results. I am attempting to align a scaled GE aerial image that I've imported into my CAD software with the CAD export of my files from ArcGIS pro.

Before I exported to CAD, I projected my layers in the WGS1984 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere) projection. I chose this projection according to what I had read best aligns with GE. In the screenshot, you can see that I've tried to use the corner of the mall buildings (center) to align the aerial with the CAD lines. The alignment between the image and the CAD building footprints falls apart quickly as you move away from this point.

Is there another projection I should use? Or do you have advice on best practices for creating CAD files that will align with Google Imagery?

The reason for trying to do this is to mock up a design in CAD using the available GIS data, but also to add a base image as a reference and to draw addition features off of (all within the CAD software).[image]

Comment: I think the nature of the aerial imagery collection methods (different camera angles) and the ortho stitching process will make aligning survey quality building footprints to that image futile.   I did a quick web search and see that you can georeference an image using AutoCAD.  Best to warp the downloaded image to conform to the building footprints.

Comment: Thank you--it is great to have that thought confirmed by someone else. Too bad!